# CSS styling when text added into element, pulls element down the page

Tags: html, css, angular, layout

I'm building a custom calculator in Angular and struggling to understand exactly what is happening here.  I have 5 div elements, set to 10vw height and width.  On start up there is nothing in the div.  I have sets of buttons which reflect 0-9, which then feed into these div elements, back to front (so effectively typing a value, with a forced decimal point at two numbers).  The problem arises when I enter a value and it populates into the div.  At this point it pulls the div down the page and continues until all 5 have a value in, then all 5 re-align to the top.

[image: CSS align issue]

I have created a working demo of this project on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-wxk1kv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbody%2Fbody.component.css).

My div elements are:

```
 <div class="value">
    <div class="box">{{ digit5 }}</div>
    <div class="box">{{ digit4 }}</div>
    <div class="box">{{ digit3 }}</div>
    .
    <div class="box">{{ digit2 }}</div>
    <div class="box">{{ digit1 }}</div>
  </div>
```

And the immediate CSS for the two elements are:

```
.value {
  font-size: 9vw;  
  text-align: center
}
.box {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 1vh 1vw;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

I'm sure this is something really simple - but I just don't understand *why*

Can anyone shed any light on what I'm doing wrong and why it's doing what its doing?

Many thanks!

Comment: vertical-align: top to box elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I would do is make two simple adjustments to two of your css classes and you will be all set.
First you should update the value class to include a display flex and to justify the content center...

```
.value {
  font-size: 9vw;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

That will fix the immidate problem you are facing and will keep the box(es) from shifting up and down... As an extra +1 tip I'd also update the .box class to have a flex-direction: column (it instead of row) and you will have a beautiful display ready to go. (Doing such will center your number in the box).

```
.box {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 1vh 1vw;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: This has worked perfectly - thank you.  I'm still getting my head around the flex options - it's a great addition (and I know it's been around for some time now), but really only fully exploring it now with this project.  Many thanks!